# Where to place Logic in MVC with ViewModel Pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I am using ViewModel in asp.net mvc 3.

In my case I have a controller which initiate a ViewModel connected to a View.

If no variable `DateForLookUp` is appended in the URL the controller initialize the ViewModel with DateTime.UctNow, otherwise it use the variable.

I need create to link on the View. When a user click the link I must take the `DateForLookUp` value and adding or subtract one day.

My question:

- Where is appropriate to place this logic, ServiceLayer, the ViewModel, the Controller or the View?

VIEW

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next Day", "Daily")

@Html.ActionLink("Previous Day", "Daily")
```

---

CONTROLLER

```
    public ActionResult Daily(string dateForLookUp)
    {
        DateTime dateTimeForLookUp;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateForLookUp))
            dateTimeForLookUp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        else 
            dateTimeForLookUp = DateTime.Parse(dateForLookUp);

        var eventsInDate = eventAggregateService.FindAllForDate(dateTimeForLookUp);
        EventsAggregateDailyListViewModel eventDailyVM = new EventsAggregateDailyListViewModel();
        eventDailyVM = new EventsAggregateDailyListViewModelBuilder().Build(eventDailyVM, dateTimeForLookUp);
        return View(eventDailyVM);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion (and in practice), I would place any and all logic in the service layer.

I break my MVC apps into several different projects to keep all layers nicely separated:

- AppName.Configuration: to handle any configuration of the app (i.e. pulling in web.config/app settings, resource files, etc.)
- AppName.Data: this is the data layer where all DB access is performed (no business logic). The DBML/EDMX lives here, my repository class(es) live here as well.
- AppName.Models: this is where all of my ViewModels are defined for MVC, as well as other model objects needed throughout the application.
- AppName.Services: This is my business layer, everything must pass through here to get to the data layer or to the presentation/web layer. ViewModels are constructed from the database objects, data validation happens here, etc.
- AppName.Web: this would be the MVC application.
- AppName.Data.Test: Unit tests for Data app
- AppName.Services.Test: Unit tests for the services
- AppName.Web.Test: Unit tests for the MVC controllers
- AppName.Web.UI.Test: Unit tests for the web user interfaces (using WATIN)

I also have a set of classes packaged up into NuGet packages that I can add to my app if/when needed, namely (for this example):

- CompanyName.Data: Common library for data layer logic
- CompanyName.MVC: Common library for ASP.NET MVC integration
- CompanyName.Utilities: Common library for miscellaneous utilities

My controllers do nothing except get the ViewModels from the service layer to send to the views and then receive the data upon post from the views and send it off to the services layer for validation, processing, saving back to the repository, other business logic, etc.